# Binding two separate instances of an interface into an object constructor

Tags: ninject

I have the following interfaces and objects

```
public interface IFoo{}
public interface IBar{}

public class Foo : IFoo {
    public Foo(IBar bar1, IBar bar2)
    {
    }
}

public class Bar1 : IBar {}
public class Bar2 : IBar {}
```

and I have the following Ninject bindings

```
Bind<IBar>()
    .To<Bar1>()
    .InSingletonScope()
    .Named("bar1");
Bind<IBar>()
    .To<Bar2>()
    .InSingletonScope()
    .Named("bar2);
Bind<IFoo>()
    .To<Foo>()
    .InSingletonScope()
    .WithConstructorArgument("bar1", context => Kernel.Get<IBar>("bar1"))
    .WithConstructorArgument("bar2", context => Kernel.Get<IBar>("bar2"));
```

Now this works, however I really do not like having to specify the constructor values to the class of 'Foo' manually. Ideally, I would like something that allowed me to say this:

*All constructor properties that have the property name of 'bar1' should use the named instance of the same name, and if the named instance does not exist, then use the default instance of 'Bar2'*

Or something along those lines.

So really, is there a better way of doing what I am trying to achieve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of having named instances, just change the constructor to be

```
public class Foo : IFoo 
{
    public Foo(IBar[] bars)
    {
    }
}
```

Then Ninject will inject an instance of each type of `IBar` registered.

Comment: The problem with this, is I have no idea which one is which. Class Foo makes decisions, and based on what the outcome of the decision, it will follow through to one instance or the other. I also have in fact, 5 instances of IBar, but only want to make use of 2 of them. I can achieve this in Castle Windsor, but I prefer to use Ninject due to Mono support.

Comment: In that case you need to move the decision process into each `IBar` have a `CanProcess()` method or something which Foo can call to find which `IBar` can handle a specific case. That also follows OCP (open-closed principle) because you can add another `IBar` which does something different without having to modify `Foo`.

Comment: I can understand that in the instance of something that perhaps handles validation, or similar scenarios. However in this instance, Foo exists purely to decide which path to continue down, if it should be "bar1" which is essentially "success" or "bar2" which is essentially "failure". So going with your idea would essentially remove the purpose of this object, and spread it's simple logic across multiple other objects.

Comment: Then you should have 2 separate interfaces `IFooSuccess` and `IFooFailure`

Comment: That's actually what I was starting to consider, but really they have the same functionality, so I was hoping to prevent duplicating like this. I'll leave this open for the rest of today, and if nothing else comes up, I think that'll probably be the best solution for my problem and I'll mark it as such. Thanks for your time and ideas!

Comment: It's better to have the intent specified by the interface type, even if it is similar to another rather than the complexity in binding and obscurity in the constructor that you have at present.

Comment: Going to have to agree with your last statement fully, as it makes it all fit together a lot easier without complex rules. I am only mildly annoyed when essentially two interfaces are practically identical in structure, however hold different intent, so splitting them feels wrong even though it just works.